# Can I have an application running on the bottom right corner

Tags: windows

Often I play a game at home where I only have to click every now and then. I would like the application which runs the game to be pinned at the bottom right hand corner of my screen so I can just click on some positions of the game every now and then, while doing other stuff online. How can I do this on a windows computer? I would like it to just be a small square or so on the bottom right hand corner

Comment: Pin that application in taskbar or in start menu.

Comment: @Biswapriyo, I pinned it, but it doesent show on the bottom right of my screen.

Comment: I want the application running in a small window like its resized on the bottom right ofm y screen and i can click on spots of it

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize the application's window to the desired size,
move it to the right spot, and set it as topmost.

Free products for setting a process to topmost can be found in the article
[Best Free Setting On-Top Windows](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-free-setting-top-windows.htm).

If this is not working, try the free
[OnTopReplica](https://github.com/LorenzCK/OnTopReplica)
from github:

> This simple utility application shows a blank always-on-top window by default. Users can pick any other window of the system to have an always up-to-date clone of the target window shown always-on-top. Very useful for monitoring background processes, wrangling with complex multi-window games or tools, watching Youtube videos while working, and so on.

Another possibility is [WindowWatcher](http://www.airesoft.co.uk/windowwatcher):

> WindowWatcher is a free hybrid window magnifier and remote control spy. It gives Windows the ability to have proper and resizable picture-in-picture support above and beyond Aero Snap. It's great for watching stuff like online TV, streams or Youtube playlists in a small corner of your workspace while working in the rest of it. It's also a fantastic help for tasks that would otherwise require flicking back and forth between windows, or to provide a simple pop-out viewer for websites and apps that don't have their own.

Comment: Thanks alot, I just realized my game wont let me make the client smaller than a specific size. Anyway I can force resize it?

Comment: You could try [5 Tools to Resize an Unresizable Window](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-resize-an-unresizable-window-or-dialog-box/).

Comment: I might have found a solution - see my updated answer.